# How do i run WinUI3 App from Commandline with arguments

Tags: .net-6.0, winui-3

I build an app like that one:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
      string[] cmdargs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
      ... Map arguments to variables ...
      ... Do stuff ...
    }
```

I'm using the framework dependend publishing without Click-Once.

I tested that app with a debug profile that contains two cmd args and it works perfectly. But if i'm trying to execute it with MyApp.exe arg1 arg2, the app starts inside the cmd but it looks, like it doesn't do anything.

Maybe i missed anything?

Comment: You need to [deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/deploy-unpackaged-apps?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) your app one way or another before you start it. Is your app unpackaged or MSIX-packaged?

Comment: @mm8: Its a unpackaged app.

Comment: Hi @SaschaManns, have you had any luck with this? I am having the same issue.